# How to get a reflection vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm doing a raytracing exercise. I have a vector representing the normal of a surface at an intersection point, and a vector of the ray to the surface. How can I determine what the reflection will be?

In the below image, I have `d` and `n`. How can I get `r`?

[image: Vector d is the ray; n is the normal; t is the refraction; r is the reflection]

Thanks.

Comment: This is question number 5.13 from I.e irodov :p

Answer (score 104, accepted):

$$r = d - 2 (d \cdot n) n$$

where $d \cdot n$ is the dot product, and
$n$ must be normalized.

Comment: And if my `d` happens to be pointing the other direction, I need to negate it first, right?

Comment: @user2755 Yes, but you can test this yourself with pencil and paper using simple cases, e.g. $d = [1,-1]; n=[0,1]$ (incoming down and to the right onto a ground plane facing upwards). With this, $r = [1,-1] - 2 \times (-1) \times [0,1] = [1,-1] + 2 \times [0,1] = [1,-1] + [0,2] = [1,1]$.

Comment: I have no idea how this works, but it works, and that's all that matters.

Comment: @rb3652 Here is my understanding.  $d\cdot n$ is the length of $d$ along the direction of $n$ (i.e., the "projection" of $d$ onto $n$).  Multiplying by $n$ turns this scalar $d\cdot n$ into a vector of length $d$ along the direction $n$.  If you substracted this from $d$, you would remove all of the $n$-direction character from $d$ (i.e., it would be perpendicular to $n$ and would be parallel to b in the diagram).  Subtracting it again yields a vector that is reflected back since you're effectively adding the $n$-direction character in the opposite direction of $d$ again.

Answer (score 89):

Let $\hat{n} = {n \over \|n\|}$. Then $\hat{n}$ is the vector of magnitude one in the same direction as $n$. The projection of $d$ in the $n$ direction is given by $\mathrm{proj}_{n}d = (d \cdot \hat{n})\hat{n}$, and the projection of $d$ in the orthogonal direction is therefore given by $d - (d \cdot \hat{n})\hat{n}$. Thus we have 
$$d = (d \cdot \hat{n})\hat{n} + [d - (d \cdot \hat{n})\hat{n}]$$
Note that $r$ has $-1$ times the projection onto $n$ that $d$ has onto $n$, while the orthogonal projection of $r$ onto $n$ is equal to the orthogonal projection of $d$ onto $n$, therefore
$$r = -(d \cdot \hat{n})\hat{n} + [d - (d \cdot \hat{n})\hat{n}]$$
Alternatively you may look at it as that $-r$ has the same projection onto $n$ that $d$ has onto $n$, with its orthogonal projection given by $-1$ times that of $d$. 
$$-r = (d \cdot \hat{n})\hat{n} - [d - (d \cdot \hat{n})\hat{n}]$$
The later equation is exactly
$$r = -(d \cdot \hat{n})\hat{n} + [d - (d \cdot \hat{n})\hat{n}]$$

Hence one can get $r$ from $d$ via
$$r = d - 2(d \cdot \hat{n})\hat{n}$$
Stated in terms of $n$ itself, this becomes
$$r = d - {2 d \cdot n\over \|n\|^2}n$$

Comment: Does this hold for vectors of any dimension? 2D, 3D, 4D, etc?

Comment: @NightElfik Abosolutely

Answer (score 8):

I was trying to understand how to calculate the reflection vector and found these answers. I couldn't understand them easily, so I took my time to do it myself, the good thing is that I can now detail it in an ELI5 fashion!

I did develop the formula using the 3 steps shown in the graphic. I describe them bellow.

[image: Steps to compute the rfection vector]

So, the initial situation is $\vec{a}$ pointing toward a plane. Then we have the normal $\vec{n}$ of unit lenght and we would like to find $\vec{b}$

So, the *first step* is using the *dot product* to get a vertical vector that will be used in *step 2*.

With *step 1* my partial formula is: $2\times\left(a+(-\vec{a})\cdot\vec{n}\times{}n\right)$

**mind the change of sign of $\vec{a}$ above, we "flipped" it**

Then in *step 2*, I can write: $-\vec{a}+2\times\left(a+(-\vec{a})\cdot\vec{n}\times{}n\right)$

Now, I can distribute:
$-\vec{a}+2\times{}\vec{a}+2\times(-\vec{a})\cdot\vec{n}\times{}n$

Then simplify, and I end up with:
$\vec{a}+2\times(-\vec{a})\cdot\vec{n}\times{}n$

If you negate a vector in the dot product, you negate the result of the dot product.

$\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=-(-\vec{a})\cdot\vec{b}$

That means that I can rewrite the formula like this:

$\vec{a}-2\times(\vec{a})\cdot\vec{n}\times{}n$

Comment: Thank you. Though the way you used Cross Product's notation as a multiplication notation confused me big time.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $d$ and $r$ have the same magnitude.
$$
\lVert r \rVert = \lVert d \rVert
$$
From the reflection relationship, we have this equality about cross products.
$$
r \times n \ = \ d \times n \\ \therefore \ \left( r \ - d \right) \times n \ = \ \vec{0}
$$
which means
$$
r \ - d \ = s \  n \\
\therefore \ r \ = \ d \ + s \ n
$$
where $s$ is a real number. 
Taking their squares, we have
$$
\lVert r \rVert ^2 \ = \ \lVert d \rVert ^2  + \ 2\ s  \left( d \cdot n  \right) \ + s^2 \ \lVert n \rVert ^2 \\
\therefore \ s \left( s \ \lVert n \rVert ^2  + \ 2 \ (d \cdot n)  \right) = 0 \\
$$
So
$$ 
 s \ = 0 \ ,  - \frac{2 \ (d \cdot n)}{\lVert  n \rVert ^2}
$$
Since $s = 0 \ $ means $ \ d \ $ itself, we take the other value and get
$$
r \ = \ d  -  \frac{2 \ (d \cdot n)}{\lVert n \rVert ^2} \ n
$$

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to rotate about Y axis you can use the following instead. This is mostly useful for computer graphics applications. Note that $d$ is assumed to be pointing outward in the equation below (i.e. ignore the direction of $d$ in the picture below) and $n$ needs to be normalized:

[image]

$$r = 2 (d \cdot n) n - d$$