# Elementary geometrical interpretation of $2\langle a,x\rangle a -x$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $V$ be an euclidean vector space with $a \in V$ of length 1.
I showed that $$f: V \rightarrow V, x \rightarrow 2\langle a,x\rangle a -x $$ is an orthogonal transformation and hence either a rotation, reflection or a combination of both.

How excatly am I supposed to figure out, what kind of transformation is taking place?

Comment: I suppose that $x$ is a vector and $\langle a,x \rangle$ is the scalar product, so it is a scalar. How you define the sum of a scalar and a vector?

Comment: corrected it. Thanks

Comment: $x\mapsto x-2\langle x,a\rangle a$ is [the orthogonal reflection](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/65525/11619) w.r.t. the hyperplane $H$ that has $a$ as its normal. So your $f$ is a reflection followed be negation. The reflection has determinant $-1$, but the determinant of negation depends on the parity of the dimension ov $V$.

Comment: Thanks, thats the answer, but I can't upvote you. How exactly did you figure that out?

Comment: The formula for the reflection is kinda well-known. And I have studied groups generated by reflections in my time.

Comment: @Hekri You're getting the story a bit backwards, I suspect.. The formula didn't come from divine revelation and then us mortals struggled to interpret it; rather, someone at some point wanted to figure out the formula for reflecting one vector $x$ across another $a$, and then successfully figured out the formula.

Comment: Here's how: every vector may be decomposed into parallel and perpendicular components (with respect to the unit vector $a$) as $x=\lambda a+b$, where $\lambda$ is some scalar component and $b$ is orthogonal to $a$. Taking the dot product yields $\langle a,x\rangle=\lambda$. The reflection of $x$ across $a$ must preserve its parallel component and negate its perpendicular component (visualize this in 3D to see this makes sense), and thus is given by $$\lambda a-b=2\lambda a-(\lambda a+b)=2\langle a,x\rangle a-x.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

By the definition of orthogonal transformation you have to prove that:
$\langle f(x),f(y)\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle \quad \forall x,y \in V$.

Calculate:
$$
\langle (2\langle a,x\rangle a -x),(2\langle a,y\rangle a -y) \rangle
$$
using the properties of the inner product, and remember that $\langle a,a\rangle=1$

---

This transformation can be interpreted as a reflection in the plane ( $2-$dimensional subspace) spanned by $a$ and $x$.

A sketch of this interpretation:

without loss of generality, we can find a basis in $span\{a,x\}$ such that $a=(1,0)$ and $x=(x_1,x_2)$

So we have $f(x)=(2x_1,0)-(x_1,x_2)=(x_1,-x_2)$

That is a reflection.

Comment: @ArnaudD.:  Sorry! Now I see !  I added something that I hope can be an answer:)

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is a linear transformation, write $f$ in matricial form. This can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\Brak}[1]{\left\langle #1\right\rangle}$A natural approach (whether you know the answer or not) is to try to compute
$$
f(x) = 2\Brak{a, x} a - x
$$
for as many vectors as you can. Here, the primary impediment is our (lack of) ability to evaluate $\Brak{a, x}$.

- Since $\|a\| = 1$, we have $\Brak{a, a} = \|a\|^{2} = 1$. Consequently,
  $$
  f(a) = 2\Brak{a, a} a - a = a.
  $$
  Success!
- If $\Brak{a, x} = 0$, i.e., $x$ is orthogonal to $a$, then
  $$
  f(x) = -x.
  $$
  Again, success!

But this answers the question: $a$ and the set of vectors orthogonal to $a$ span $V$, so we've found the eigenspace decomposition of $f$.