# How can i reflect position and direction vectors from a plane

Tags: vectors, 3d, reflection

I'm now working on a project that has mirrors. I'd like to reflect a virtual camera and the way which i can do this is to reflect two vectors - position and normalized direction vectors of the camera. The plane itself is just a position and a normal. I already tried googling something but no luck with it. Can someone please share some formulas that may fit or suggest a better way to do it?

Comment: Answered in this post:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13261/how-to-get-a-reflection-vector